# generate a date string in HTTP response date format in C

Tags: c, date

I'm trying to generate a date string from current time to put into HTTP response header. It looks like this:

```
Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2010 08:12:31 GMT
```

I only have the default C library to work with. How do I do this?

Comment: [`time.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/time.h.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html), declared in `<time.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  char buf[1000];
  time_t now = time(0);
  struct tm tm = *gmtime(&now);
  strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &tm);
  printf("Time is: [%s]\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

See the [code "running" at codepad](http://codepad.org/x9NqQc3g).

Comment: So clean! The RFC detailing the desired format is called IMF-fixtime, and is detailed here: [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1). Using `gmtime` when translating the time_t to a struct tm is a subtle but important part in conforming with standards!

Comment: With `strftime`, the day and month names are locale-dependent, but the HTTP spec requires English names, so I think this won't work correctly in non-English locales.

Comment: Good point @wch. To OP: save the locale first, set locale to `"C"`, reset to saved ... `char savedlocale[256]; strcpy(savedlocale,  setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)); setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); /* code in my answer */; setlocale(LC_ALL, savedlocale);`

Comment: Thanks have been searching for this format string for almost an hour!

Comment: This is the output for me: "Fri, 17 Mar 2023 09:31:54 Romance Standard Time". Not sure why the "%Z" part is not GTM.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to avoid `strftime()` as it is impacted by locales and write your own function:

```
void http_response_date(char *buf, size_t buf_len, struct tm *tm)
{
    const char *days[] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    const char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
        "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    snprintf(buf, buf_len, "%s, %d %s %d %02d:%02d:%02d GMT",
        days[tm->tm_wday], tm->tm_mday, months[tm->tm_mon],
        tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
}

int http_response_date_now(char *buf, size_t buf_len)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    if (now == -1)
        return -1;

    struct tm *tm = gmtime(&now);
    if (tm == NULL)
        return -1;

    http_response_date(buf, buf_len, tm);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output as of the time of writing: `Tue, 20 Oct 2020 22:28:01 GMT`. The output length will be 28 or 29 (if the month day >= 10), so a 30 char buffer is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your platform has `strftime` : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html .

Comment: The C89 Standard includes `strftime`. I assume all C implementations done in the last 20 years have it. Also you might want to update your POSIX link (to [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/))

Answer (score -1):

Use gmtime(3) + mktime(3).
You will end up with a struct tm that has all that information.

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```